# Brown Dust on Hubcap

Tags: brakes

[image]there is significant brown dust on the front of both hubcaps
is this a drum, disc or pad problem....Car also squeaks when braking,
bought car six months ago and noticed browning yesterday

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! A picture of what you're talking about would go a long way. Brown dust is usually a sign of brake dust, but who knows at this point.

Comment: @Nonie please upload a picture for us to inspect

Comment: Pic has been uploaded

Answer (score 1):

As advised this is a dust residue from the brake pads wearing as they interact with the disks.. As you have now noticed squeaking/squealing from the area its time to have the front brakes inspected as soon as possible, just to make sure that the pads have a suitable amount of friction material left on them, if they are low they will require replacing.

Answer (score 0):

brown blackish residue can be normal... it is a dust accumilation caused by friction of brake pads on brake disc\drum . Squeaking also sometimes common and may go away with time or use